# Arquillian and CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I'm reading the Arquillian Reference Guide which is very well written, however in the chapter that talks about setting up dependency injection I can't find where you actually specify the beans/bindings.

Most of the Arquillian CDI code examples show the use of Java's `@Inject` annotation. So I'm just wondering, where I define these beans/DI mappings/bindings, and how do I configure Arquillian to use them?

**In Spring DI, you specify a bean descriptor, like `spring-config.xml`. In Guice you implement a `Module` and define its `configure(Binder)` method. What does this look like in Arquillian-land when using `javax.inject.Inject`?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer** - there is no need to define bean mappings in CDI, because CDI works with annotations exclusively. You can add extra information in config-files, but this is usually not required.

**The long answer** is best taken from [this excellent introduction](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/) into CDI.

Comment: Thanks @jan groth (+1) - So if my Arquillian integration test has a `private @Inject Fruit fruit` field, and I want that `fruit` interface to be injected with an `Apple` instance inside the container, how do I configure that binding?

Comment: `private @Inject Fruit fruit` if there is one implementation of Fruit, `private @Inject @Apple Fruit fruit` if there are more. But you should go through the referenced introduction, that's way too much to explain here...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ["Alternatives"](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#alternatives) CDI mechanism

> Alternatives are beans whose implementation is specific to a particular client module or deployment scenario.

Comment: This is not how alternatives are intended to work. Using xml for to manage such a common thing would be pretty terrible. Correct answer is @jan groth

Comment: Ok, what for then we need alternatives? :)

Comment: Actually, in context of integration testing with Arquillian, as was mentioned by OP in comment to @jan's answer, I think this is indeed the simplest way of specifying alternative implementation of a bean